# Changing the JLabel text from another class doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I have two classes `MainFrame` and `Test`. `MainFrame` class contains two components a `JButton` and a `JLabel`.

I want the text of `JLabel` to be changed when I invoke `setText()` method from `Test` class by creating an instance of `MainFrame` in `Test` class, when I click the `JButton`.  But unfortunately neither the `setText()` nor the `getText()` work from `Test` class. How can I achieve it?

Here's my code.

**MainFrame.java**:

```
    public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public MainFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        labelToSet = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        clickMeButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        labelToSet.setText("Hello");

        clickMeButton.setText("Click me");
        clickMeButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                clickMeButtonActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(84, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(clickMeButton)
                .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                .addComponent(labelToSet)
                .addGap(110, 110, 110))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(98, 98, 98)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(labelToSet)
                    .addComponent(clickMeButton))
                .addContainerGap(79, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }                       

    /*Code to be concentrated*/
    private void clickMeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
        Test t = new Test();
    }                                             

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public javax.swing.JButton clickMeButton;
    public javax.swing.JLabel labelToSet;                   
}
```

**Test.java**:

```
public class Test {

    Test() {
        MainFrame mf = new MainFrame();
        System.out.println(mf.labelToSet.getText());
        mf.labelToSet.setText("Goodbye!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are changing the text of `labelToSet` in a *different instance* of the class `MainFrame`, an instance that is never shown on screen.

If you want your code in the constuctor of `Test` to change the text of the label that is already being shown, you need to pass it a reference to that `MainFrame` object.

Change your `Test` constructor to accept that reference:

```
public class Test {
    Test(MainFrame mf) {
        mf.labelToSet.setText("Goodbye!");
    }
}
```

And call it accordingly (passing the reference `this` to the `MainFrame` object that is currently being shown):

```
private void clickMeButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    Test t = new Test(this);
}
```